# Reading entire table from data base

Tags: database, oracle, pagination

My use case is that I need to read all the rows from a table and populate the cache (may not be ideal cache but say thats my use case). In this case do I have to do a paginated query to database or just issue `select *` and use some reasonable fetch size? Please advice.

Comment: Well, how big is this table?

Comment: 3 million to start with. Expected to grow bigger

Comment: This will bring it into the cache and then it'll then be aged back out of the cache. Do you actually have a specific performance issue to be solved? Maybe you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975921/how-to-pin-a-table-to-oracle-dbms-shared-pool-in-11g. Or maybe you need to use this IMDB technology: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/timesten/tt1121/2_caching_imdbcache/2_caching_imdbcache.htm

Comment: My data is mostly static and I want to put entire data set or most of it for faster access. So aging is not an issue for me. I will load this data at the service start up only.

Comment: And I explicitly remove it from cache when client tells me to remove it. Say that particular data item not in use, soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you would need the entire table (assuming you got enough memory) then just do a Select * , this way you won't stress the database couple times by doing multiple select and restrict fetch size. Again there are trade offs. By doing so the users will be waiting there with no display until database returns everything and got processed.